# How can I pass AWS Configs to Flink's flink-s3-fs-hadoop plugin in local tests?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

**Problem Summary**

- I am trying to run a local integration test for my flink app, which reads parquet files from AWS s3, does some transformations, and writes the output back to s3; I am using the below:

  - Flink's parquet format for the source: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/parquet/
  - localstack/testcontainers to spin up a local s3 on localhost
  - junit5 to run my tests
  - Flink minicluster to run my app during the test
  - IntelliJ IDEA
  - Flink version 1.17.0, maven, and java 11
- Because the flink app interacts with s3 (I believe the parquet format above requires it), I have `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` as a test dependency in my project
- **The issue**:

  - There seems to be no way to pass all required AWS configs to the S3 client that the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` plugin uses
  - Due to the above, a local test using Flink & AWS s3 is not currently possible; I run into `AmazonS3Exception 403 Forbidden` when my source tries to read the parquet files that I put in localstack s3
  - The AWS configs I need to pass are below:

    - s3.access-key
    - s3.secret-key
    - s3.endpoint
    - s3.endpoint.region
    - s3.path.style.access
- Note: the application works in "prod" because it runs on EMR; it's just locally that this issue occurs

**What I Have Tried**

1. Adding AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ENDPOINT_URL, and AWS_REGION as environment variables (IntelliJ run configurations)

   - Before I set these I was getting an error that the access key and secret key could not be found, so I believe these were able to get picked up (makes sense given https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authenticating_via_the_AWS_Environment_Variables)
   - The other environment variables are not getting picked up; I confirmed by running my app in debug mode and looking at the AmazonS3 client params
2. Adding a `conf/flink-conf.yaml` under my test resources folder and setting the following environment variable `FLINK_CONF_DIR=src/test/resources/conf`

   - It seemed that Flink could find the file, but it did not pass any of the values to the plugin
3. Creating a local execution environment with the aws configs specified (see code below)

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("s3.access-key", "test");
        props.put("s3.secret-key",  "test");
        props.put("s3.endpoint", "http://localstack:4566");
        props.put("s3.endpoint.region", "us-east-1");
        props.put("s3.path.style.access", "true");
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationUtils.createConfiguration(props);
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(16, configuration);
```

4. I spun up a Flink cluster (jobmanager + taskmanager) locally using docker-compose, added the AWS configs as k,v pairs within the FLINK_PROPERTIES environment variable (which then appends to the flink-conf), enabled the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` plugin, and confirmed that the flink app works correctly when submitted to this cluster (i.e. this confirmed that the app works when the configs are added and available to the plugin)

   - Note: even though this way works, it is not good enough for my use-case; I need to be able to run a test within an automated test suite like Junit

```
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "awslocal"
    image: localstack/localstack:1.4.0
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
      - "127.0.0.1:4571:4571"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=1
      - LS_LOG=trace
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}localstack
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  jobmanager:
    container_name: "jobmanager"
    image: flink:1.17.0-java11
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        s3.access-key: test
        s3.secret-key: test
        s3.endpoint: http://awslocal:4566
        s3.endpoint.region: us-east-1
        s3.path.style.access: true
      - ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS=flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.17.0.jar
    volumes:
      - /Users/myname/IdeaProjects/my-flink-app/target:/opt/flink/usrlib
  taskmanager:
    container_name: "taskmanager"
    image: flink:1.17.0-java11
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
        s3.access-key: test
        s3.secret-key: test
        s3.endpoint: http://awslocal:4566
        s3.endpoint.region: us-east-1
        s3.path.style.access: true
      - ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS=flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.17.0.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

1- Create your test config file (flink-config.yaml) with

```
## S3 config
s3.access-key: test
s3.secret-key: test
s3.endpoint: http://awslocal:4566
s3.endpoint.region: us-east-1
s3.path.style.access: true
```

2- Load this configuration with

```
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

Configuration loadedConfig = GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration("directory/where/is/flinkconfig");
FileSystem.initialize(config, null);
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(loadedConfig);
```

The important part is `FileSystem.initialize(config, null);`

Comment: `FileSystem.initialize(config, null)` did the trick, thank you!